# Can I create a Telegram bot so that members’ questions can be sent to it and the admin can answer them?

Tags: bots, telegram, telegram-bot, admin, group

I want to create a Telegram bot where people can send their questions instead of sending them to the admin in private so what can i do

I created a bot but I couldn't get the thing I wanted I made several attempts and I did not even see the message being sent to the bot

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

If user sends question you need to send one to admin.chat.id with button "Answer", after some manipulations with callbacks you can send the answer in user.chat.id

//P.s. I can help you with this

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

We have created a simple bot for our support team. The flow is next:

- You need a private group for your support team (private so that it cannot be found in public search)
- Add your bot to the group, so it is aware and ignores any non-related messages in the group id
- Whenever user sends a message to your bot - forward to your group id (+ thread id if needed)
- Whenever anybody from the group replies to the message - your bot will get this update and can forward it back to the sender of the original message

You also might create threads if needed for different parts of your team (e.g. product support, technical support, marketing etc.) and from here you can go creative - either bot determines the target support team (e.g. question is about marketing or user selects type of request or you have ML model to determine the request) or your team forwards from general thread to specific ones.

Answer (score 0):

You can use telegram chatbot software, in this software will auto reply as per answer predefined on software.

Here is link for telegram chatbot

https://codecanyon.net/item/telegram-chatbot-pro/46250125